# Why I can't use a style in table?

Tags: html, css

```
<table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="230px">
            <span style="size:11px;">NAZWA</div>
            </td>
            <td width="230px;">
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

but it doesn't works. Also any style with class and id doesn't work for me in table.

Comment: Use the right syntax and it will work. `font-size`

Comment: @Pekka : This should be answer, with example...

Comment: More eyes means more things get spotted. I didn't spot all three errors before answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `font-size`

```
 <span style="font-size:11px;">NAZWA</span>
```

Comment: Thanks,  my stupid mistake... :)

Comment: You are welcome. It happens :)

Answer (score 1):

in [table cells](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.6), `width` is already in pixels, so use `width="230"`. It is not CSS, it is pure HTML. Keep in mind that the width attribute has been deprecated, and you should use CSS `style="width: 230px"`, preferably on [table columns](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.4).

Plus what @Pekka said about `font-size`. And what @FahimParkar said about the `</div>`.

Answer (score 0):

### Point 1

what you have is

```
<td width="230px">
    <span style="size:11px;">NAZWA</div>
</td>
```

You are opening `span` but closing it as `</div>`.

### Point 2

Also above can be achieved as

```
<td width="230px" style="font-size:11px">
    NAZWA
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

your code should be like this

```
<table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="230px">
                <span style="font-size:11px;">NAZWA</span>
            </td>
            <td width="230px;">
            </td>
    </tr>  </table>
```